# Wifi - bring wlan0 up on boot

Tags: wireless, raspbmc, networking

I have my network setting stored in `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` and my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo, eth0, wlan0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To connect to the network I have to run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` followed by `sudo ifup wlan0` after every boot. Not ideal as im running `raspbmc`

How can I get `wlan0` up and connect on boot, I have tried added the commands to `/etc/rc.local` but that didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't `wpa-conf /etc/wpa.conf` be `wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to point to your wireless network settings?  I just got WiFi working on `raspbmc` last night.  When I get home today I'll test how my setup behaves across reboots.

Comment: Opps was a typo in the question not in my settings however. `/etc/network/interfaces` points to the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I also suspect that `iface iface lo inet loopback` is also a typo, should be `iface lo inet loopback`.  Loopback interface configuration.

Comment: *Damn my lack of proof reading skills*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I changed `auto` to `allow-hotplug` for wlan0 in my `/etc/network/interfaces`, see below:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
#auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

That worked for me!

I'm really not sure why this worked.  The Debian documentation at [this link](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_basic_syntax_of_etc_network_interfaces) is confusing to me because this is all new to me, however the `ifquery` command shown below now returns wlan0 and this command is used by `/etc/init.d/networking` to determine which interfaces to bring up.  Previously with wlan0 as auto, `ifquery --list --alow=hotplug` didn't return anything.

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ ifquery --list --allow=hotplug
wlan0
```

Comment: I've spent ages trying to get my device online. why does the google not spit this out immediately? :) thank you <3

Comment: If this answer does not work (I can't say for 2012, but it does not in 2019), consider replacing `dhcp` with `manual`.

Answer (score 7):

Your original config was ok, except for the comma's in your first line.

So use `auto lo eth0 wlan0` instead...

My config:

```
  auto lo wlan0

  iface lo inet loopback

  iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

  iface default inet static
    address 10.0.0.81
    network 10.0.0.0
    netmask 255.255.254.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

~

Comment: Darn commas had me screwed up on Debian Jessie. Does anyone know why commas seem to work on some Debian Wheezy but not Jessie?

Answer (score 1):

> Note to future readers: As of today, the current RPi OS is `buster`. If the OS you are using is **not** `buster`, you should find a more current answer as this may be outdated.

It's now March, 2021. This question was asked in Oct, 2012, and things have changed some in 8+ years! I don't know why this Q&A is being re-cycled, but I'm submitting this answer because I feel this Q&A is ***confusing and misleading***. I won't review or comment upon the answers here beyond the obvious: they are ***old***.

In `buster` the `wlan0` interface should come up automatically at boot time without any intervention or configuration on your part - provided you have followed the latest [instructions for setting up the wireless LAN in the *official* documentation.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md)