# Connecting Raspberry Pi B to wireless network?

Tags: hardware, wireless

**Connecting Raspberry Pi to wireless network?**

How do I connect my Raspberry Pi B to my wireless network?

Comment: Please search this site before asking questions. YOur question has been covered many times and has allot of valuable questions. Please read the [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq) too.

Comment: [List of Wireless questions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=wireless)

Comment: So is there an exact duplicate that this could be closed against?

Comment: Guys, please stop flagging this for mods. If you can see a duplicate then vote to close. This does not need moderator intervention.

Comment: I wish... "Vote to Close" requires 500 reputation (3000 out of private beta)

Answer (score 5):

I'm running [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com) on my Pi and I use [this USB WiFi adapter](http://www.adafruit.com/products/814) available from Adafruit.

[image]

I had to make the changes shown in this [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/wifi-bring-wlan0-up-on-boot/3206#3206) to get this interface to come up automatically after a reboot.  The driver for this adapter was already in the Raspbmc kernel.  It is my understanding that this driver is also in Raspbian Wheezy.

Here's a [link](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#Working_USB_Wifi_Adapters) to known working USB WiFi adapters for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Raspbian on my Pi, and I use an 'RTL8192cu' based USB WiFi adapter.

Configuration was easy:

#### Step 1 - `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`:

(modified for your wireless network settings, of course)

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-scan-ssid 1
   wpa-ap-scan 1
   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
   wpa-proto RSN WPA
   wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
   wpa-group CCMP TKIP
   wpa-ssid "MYNETWORKNAME"
   wpa-psk "MYNETWORKPASSWORD"
iface default inet dhcp
```

#### Step 2 - `sudo reboot`

When the Pi comes up it should automatically connect to your wireless network.

If it does not, you can check and see if there is an existing discussion for your specific hardware, software, etc.